# Zookeeper status - telnet connections: 4

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Could someone help me to understand is it required to have 4 connections for zookeeper.

My requirement is simple - I want to run a apache kafka with spark in my local machine. As per the kafka documentation I had started the zookeeper under the kafka bin and wanted to confirm if my zookeeper is up.

So, tried "telnet localhost 2181" from the command prompt.

And got the below ouput:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
Zookeeper version: 3.4.5--1, built on 06/10/2013 17:26 GMT
Clients:
 /127.0.0.1:34231[1](queued=0,recved=436,sent=436)
 /127.0.0.1:34230[1](queued=0,recved=436,sent=436)
 /127.0.0.1:37719[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
 /127.0.0.1:34232[1](queued=0,recved=436,sent=436)

Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/42
Received: 2127
Sent: 2136
Connections: 4
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x143
Mode: standalone
Node count: 51
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I would like to know as why the connection is saying 4 with 4 clients. what does that actually mean?

Thank you in advance to help me understand if 4 clients are required.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know as why the connection is saying 4 with 4 clients. what does that actually mean?

It means there are currently four connections open to zookeeper. This connection:

```
 /127.0.0.1:37719[0](queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
```

is your `telnet localhost 2181` connection.

Comment: Please ignore this as it is old post